# Calling dispose() for Font in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, dispose, idisposable

I've been running into the same issue as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769908/how-and-when-is-font-disposed-for-winforms-controls). That is, Fortify complained about the creation of font objects, for which the `new Font()` statements are generated code in the designer.cs files. When looking at profiling results I do get the impreesion I need to do something about this, at least in some cases.

This is, of course, an issue only if the develper has assigned a font of his choice to the form in the graphical designer. My plan is to undo that choice and to create the Font manually after the call to `InitializeComponent()` and then call `dispose()` for the Font in the `dispose()` method of the form. Since that way I do create the resource myself (and checked whether it is used elsewhere) I'm sure it is not shared and can safely allow it's disposal. Up to that point I'm rather confident about the issue.

Now the `dispose()` method of the form is generated as well when the form is created and has a boolean `disposing` parameter. What I'm uncertain about (and this is my question) is whether I can ignore this parameter, or have to check it for true or false before calling `font.dispose()`. (I have to admit I do not yet understand the dispose logic in these generated winforms).

More specifically: the generated code looks as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Assuming a font for form 'myForm' is affected, I'd create it using

```
... 
InitializeComponent(); // this is generated into the constructor
this.myForm.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("NiftFontName",...);
...
```

and would call `this.myForm.Dispose()`to dispose it. The question is, where in the forms' `dispose()` method this should go.

Comment: No, don't do that.  Fonts are very expensive objects to create, they are kept in a cache so they are cheap to re-use.  Fortify just isn't nearly smart enough to know this.  The Microsoft code analyzer is, it can read the [SuppressMessage] attribute that the Font class has.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is, where in the forms' dispose() method this should go.

Here is a simple rule from Microsoft:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (disposing) {
      // Free any managed objects here. 
   }

   // Free any unmanaged objects here. 
}
```

Read [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

So if your font is loaded from a font file, for instance, then it is unmanaged and you should dispose it outside the `if (disposing)` block.

Answer (score 2):

Control font properties are weird.  With most controls, setting the `Font` property will cause a control to take a snapshot of that `Font`'s characteristics and render itself appropriately.  The control will not dispose of the font, nor will it care if the font is disposed; even if the font is disposed *before it's assigned the control's `Font` property* the control will still take a snapshot of the font's characteristics (which remain readable to the control's snapshot method even when a font is disposed) and use that.  Note that not all controls work this way, and I don't know how to emulate this behavior with user controls that do their own drawing.  Nonetheless, with some types of controls, the seemingly-nonsensical

```
using (Font myFont = new Font(Whatever))
  theButton.Font = myFont;
```

will work just fine.  Even

```
myFont = new Font(Whatever);
myFont.Dispose();
theButton.Font = myFont;
```

would work.  I suspect `Font` was designed before Microsoft realized the "ownership" problems posed by sharable immutable disposable objects; auto-generated code is very sloppy with `Dispose` semantics, so it's probably not necessary to do too much better in most cases.

Comment: So there is no need to use the using construct?

Comment: @Revious: In the case of `Font` objects which are used exlusively for the purpose of setting control properties, it would appear that the normal usage patterns for `IDisposable` aren't really applicable since `Dispose` will only cleanup parts of the objects that aren't needed for the purpose of setting control properties.  Such patterns are applicable for most other kinds of `IDisposable` objects, however.

Comment: thanks, if I use font and other objects for GDI Drawing the garbage collector should collect them as soon as I exit the block of code in which they are defined?

Comment: @Revious: A `Font` which has been disposed will no longer be usable for GDI drawing.  Setting a control's `Font` property does not cause the control to use that font for drawing, however, but instead causes it to make a copy of the font's properties--something that can be done even after the `Font` is disposed.

Comment: @Revious: I think the .NET design would have been cleaner if there were separate `FontDescription` and `DrawingFont` types; the latter type would be suitable for GDI drawing and would implement `IDisposable`, while the former would be used for setting control properties but would not implement `IDisposable`.  The design is pretty well locked in stone by now, though.

Comment: @SuperCat, If you do this while the form or the control has not been shown yet (no handle created) then an _'ArgumentException'_ occurs when the control **is** shown. The exception is triggered in the ToLogFont method, started from 'System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback'...
It **will** bring down your application. Tested with a Label and a TextBox