# Unreleased Resource:Unmanaged Object

Tags: c#, fortify

I have a fortify issues at the `new font()` line of the code

> Unreleased Resource:Unmanaged Object  -Fortify c#

Code:

```
try
{
 var c = new ChartArea();
 c.AxisY.TitleFont =  new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);// --> Fortify issue
}
finally
{
  if (ca.AxisY.TitleFont!= null)
      {
        ca.AxisY.TitleFont.Dispose(); //--> does not resolve the foritfy issue
      }
}
```

I have tried to dispose the titlefont, but it does not help. Can you please let me know how to solve this issue?

Fortify details message:

> The function DrawChart() in  DrawController.cs fails to properly
>   dispose of unmanaged system resources allocated by Font() on line 134.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling dispose() for Font in Windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661480/calling-dispose-for-font-in-windows-form)

Comment: Static analyzers rarely get this correct.  They just can't look deep enough to see that the Font should *not* be disposed and that this happens much later.  Automatically, when the user is done looking at the chart.  Just suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if the act of assigning the new Font to .TitleFont throws an exception. In that case, .TitleFont may still be null but the Font object would have been allocated and you have not retained a handle to it.

A little bit more typing will probably resolve the problem:

```
var c = null;
Font arial10bold = null;
try
{
 c = new ChartArea();
 arial10bold = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
 c.AxisY.TitleFont =  arial10bold;
}
finally
{
  if ( arial10bold != null ) {
      arial10bold.Dispose;
  }
}
```